# C# Tools for Model Based Test

Tags: c#, model-based-testing

I am new in Model Based Testing. Can you advice which tools can be used to develop Model Based Test in C#. Is it normal to use NModel? Or it's obsolet? What tools is used now?

Comment: Visit http://robertvbinder.com/open-source-tools-for-model-based-testing/ site to get list of open source Model Based Testing Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ["which tool should I pick?" questions are specifically called out as off-topic](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).